# Connection between the sawtooth Fourier series and the Euler-Mascheroni constant?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, euler-mascheroni-constant

I've been studying the slope of the sawtooth waveform $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{sin(nx)}{x}$$ And found that, for $x \in (0, 2\pi)$, its graph seems to line up perfectly with the line $$y = \frac{x}{2}+\gamma+1$$ Where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant, $\approx.57721566...$ What is this constant doing here?

Comment: Do you mean to have $n$ in the denominator of the summand? Also, at $x=0^+$, you would have $y=\frac\pi2\approx \gamma+1$

Comment: @ТymaGaidash Yes.

Comment: Do you know about [Euler-Maclaurin Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula)?

Comment: @LuckyChouhan I know about it, but I don't really understand it

Comment: @ТymaGaidash You're right, $\pi /2$ is a much more accurate constant than $\gamma + 1$

Comment: yeah @ТymaGaidash but it is actually $y = \frac{-x}{2} + \frac{\pi}{2}$ see here [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/4r5ken0qzo)